# How do I solve this error: symbol cublasLtHSHMatmulAlgoInit version libcublasLt.so.11 not defined in file libcublasLt.so.11 with link time reference

Tags: python, torch, clip, openai-api, oserror

I am trying to import the torch into the jupyter notebook But when I ran initially, my code was working, and when I restarted the kernel and reran this block of code, I got the below error. How do I resolve this?

`import torch` ,
`import clip`

I am getting the same error even when running these two imports separately.

*OSError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so.11: symbol cublasLtHSHMatmulAlgoInit version libcublasLt.so.11 not defined in file libcublasLt.so.11 with link time reference*

Comment: What are the system details? Python version, conda version, OS, CUDA version, etc.

Comment: Python version: 3.7, Os is ubuntu, and I am running this on the Google cloud platform. these are the specific features are environment: NumPy/SciPy/scikit-learn, machine type: 4 vCPUs,15 GB RAM, GPU: NVIDIA T4 x 1

Comment: Yes, but what version of CUDA and Conda and other packages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case, but in mine I was working on my project on a device without a GPU and then I moved the entire code to another that does have a GPU. At that time this same error appeared. There I realized that the version of torch that I moved does not have the files associated with cuda, so I simply uninstalled torch and reinstalled it again, that is:

```
pip unistall torch
pip install torch=(version you need)
```

And voila! all done.

Greetings and I hope my experience helps.